# Connection reset by peer after 8 minutes

Tags: php, mod-fastcgi

I get connection reset by peer after 8 min

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
```

Here is fcgi.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
#FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 2000
#FcgidMaxProcesses 100
#FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
FcgidIOTimeout 6000
#FcgidIdleTimeout 3600
#FcgidIdleScanInterval 30
#FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
#FcgidBusyScanInterval 90
#FcgidErrorScanInterval 3
#FcgidZombieScanInterval 3
#FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
</IfModule>
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: what is your max_execution_time in php.ini ?

Comment: 6000 is the max_excecution_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be because you commented out `FcgidBusyTimeout` thus falling back to the default value, 300 which is 5 minutes. More at https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidbusytimeout

Comment: You're probably right. How could I miss it. Really embarrassing.